# Chromecast videos are not autoplaying m3u8 file

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I using Google [example](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloVideo-ios) for work with Chromecast.

Working with mp4 files is correct.

But if I want to use the **m3u8** format, the video will not start playing.

If I rewind the video by 10 seconds ahead, it starts playing. But it doesn't play when rewinding from 0 to 9 seconds, even if you rewind before forward for more than 10 seconds.

This is my code:

```
func playVideoRemotely() {

    GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().presentDefaultExpandedMediaControls()

    let url = URL(string: "http://www.streambox.fr/playlists/test_001/stream.m3u8")

    guard let mediaURL = url else {
        print("invalid mediaURL")
        return
    }

    let mediaInfoBuilder = GCKMediaInformationBuilder(contentURL: mediaURL)

    mediaInfoBuilder.contentID = "http://www.streambox.fr/playlists/test_001/stream.m3u8"
    mediaInfoBuilder.streamType = GCKMediaStreamType.buffered
    mediaInfoBuilder.contentType = "video/m3u8"

    mediaInformation = mediaInfoBuilder.build()

    guard let mediaInfo = mediaInformation else {
        print("invalid mediaInformation")
        return
    }

    if let request = sessionManager.currentSession?.remoteMediaClient?.loadMedia(mediaInfo) {
        request.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not development on an iOS chromecast sender, but have done it on web. If you want the video to autoplay once it is loaded then I believe you need to set the autoplay field on the [load options](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_media_load_options.html#a4f298b6f00702a98619ef19cc22feb3f).

Comment: I have another problem.
If I rewind the video for example for 0:50 it will be played. But if after that I rewind it for 0:05, then it will not play.

Comment: When you rewind are you doing it when the content is paused or playing?

Comment: Сontent is playing

Comment: I'm not sure what could be causing that, I tried to reproduce with no luck.

Comment: Is your video playing without problems?

Comment: The only issue I notice when seeking backwards (when playing or paused) is that it takes really long to finish buffering, but this is probably just related to my internet speed. I'm using m3u8 aswell.